# Most efficient way to look up another dataframe based on criteria, for packing problem by 3D dimensions and weight

Tags: python, pandas, bin-packing

So the context of this problem: I have two pandas dataframes:

- list of products that I sell on Amazon.com, with their three packaging dimensions (W x H x L) and packaging weight
- list of the Amazon fees breakdown and weight threshold (Left hand dataframe)

  - Here is the way that Amazon charge sellers fees: if your three product box dimensions (greatest side, middle side and lowest side) plus your weight fall underneath a threshold's limits then it gets assigned that 'row'.
- in the screenshot these dataframes are shown on right and left respectively.

What I want to do is **create some kind of mass lookup type operation with multiple conditions** (like Excel VLOOKUP) to find the row in the Amazon fee breakdown dataframe that meets the fee that the product will be charged. I basically need to figure out which category number it goes into, as you can see with the yellow highlighted cells.

Is there a simple way to do this with Pandas that doesn't involve loops, numerous if statements / etc.

My thinking is that there is some kind of filter or iloc/loc statement that could be written within pandas that would be fairly simple, to identify the row and add it as a value in a new column.

I effectively need to create a query for each product that finds the first row in the Amazon fee dataframe (working bottom to top):

Where Largest-Side is lower than Largest-side-max
AND WHERE Middle-dim is lower than Middle-Size-Max
AND WHERE Lowest-side is lower than Lowest-Size-max
AND WHERE Weight is lower than Weight

I do not need a full answer, more pointing in right direction of most efficient way to handle, as it will be eventually used for thousands of products.

First data frame is

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th align="center">abc</th>
<th align="right">defghi</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center">bar</td>
<td align="right">baz</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The screenshot did not attach properly. Here is it;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/34t7x.png

Comment: Similar to this box packing problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67990078/does-the-product-fit-into-the-carton

Comment: Sure, but we really need you to give us example data, post the dataframes directly here, not links to screenshots. Also, it makes life easier to give your dataframes names: `dimensions` and `fee_schedule`.

Comment: Are you only shipping one item? Because if you're shipping multiple items in one package, this becomes a [tag:knapsack-problem]. Specifically, [tag:bin-packing]. If so, see e.g. [knapsack algorithm for packing boxes by item dimension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59568886/is-there-a-knapsack-algorithm-for-packing-boxes-by-item-dimension) or [Toy box challenge - E-commerce Shipment / Container splitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489295/toy-box-challenge-e-commerce-shipment-container-splitting)